# SRV Record for Service X

Tags: dns

I've got a quite common question, which I can't find an answer for.

Is it possible to create a SRV Record for any possible service I'm running? For example: I want `webinterface.example.com` to redirect to `example.com:1234`

The corresponding `SRV` record would be `_WebInterface._TCP IN SRV 1 255 1234 example.com.`

We've set up something similar but it's not working as intended.

Comment: Are you sure the **application** uses the SRV record? You can put anything you want in the DNS it then needs to be specifically requested for by some application. And web browsers specifically do not use SRV records....

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI alyer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a SRV Record for any possible "service" I'm running?

Yes

> The corresponding SRV Record would be
> "`_WebInterface._TCP IN SRV 1 255 1234 example.com`"

I'd personally reduce the size of the service name to `_httpd._tcp.company.local`

Questions?  [RFC 2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) is a good resource and includes a fictitious example on page 7.

Comment: It is not a question of size, the first underscore field is the service as defined in http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers (`/etc/services` in Unix systems), so it is not a freeform value. The second underscore field is hence `_udp` or `_tcp`.

Comment: I didn’t say size was an important issue

Comment: You wrote: " I'd personally reduce the size " :-) the problem is not size at all.... `_WebInterface` is not among the list of services defined in IANA registry hence invalid, so it should be `_http` probably in this context. Which is shorter indeed but this is only a side effect.

Comment: Your understanding of English isn’t terribly refined in this case.  Expressing a personal preference in no way means it should be important to the reader (or anyone else).  A personal preference is just me saying what I like

Comment: BTW there is no mention of service records conforming to the IANA registry in the RFC.  How did you decide that’s important to SRV records?

Comment: There is: "Service
        The symbolic name of the desired service, as defined in Assigned
        Numbers [STD 2] or locally."  STD2 being RFC1700 superseded by RFC3232 that basically transition over to http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers. Now I am sure you will argue about the "or locally" which enables you to do everything you want I guess... except if you want some interoperability and some clients finding your services in which case you need to stick to the IANA list (or control all clients).

Comment: You might also be interested by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-attrleaf/ and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-attrleaf-fix/

Comment: And thanks for your condescending remarks by the way... English is not my mother tongue indeed, so what? You were still expressing opinion on size (which is irrelevant, the size not the opinion) without stating what I feel **personally** to be more important, that is to use values conforming to the standard...

Comment: Saying you're not understanding something is not condescending.  Try not to be the guy who runs off expressing offense at trivial things.

Comment: You did not state I do not understand something you said : "Your understanding of English isn’t terribly refined in this case. "  this is a generic ("understanding of English") condescending ("isn't terribly refined") remark, almost an ad hominem attack. Purely unneeded here, but "whatever you say". And this new comment of yours is indeed again a passive aggressive attack, against useless. I will stop arguing with you then since you are not really discussing facts anymore and just do not like someone disagreeing with you. Sorry about that.

Comment: Saying your understanding of English isn't refined in this case is not substatially different than "you're not understanding something".  You seem to be the guy who loves to argue.  I'm sure you'll try to take some "last shot", which I'll gladly take instead of wasting my time on this minutia

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind comments and sacrifice. You sure did not waste time to address the core facts...

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/understanding-narcissism/201710/how-de-escalate-fight-narcissist

Comment: I love how you edited that question to correct the OP's example

Comment: Thank you for your link to understand how to de-escalate the fight with someone like you, very much useful indeed :-) And I am very happy you appreciate my edit on the OP example.

Comment: That's a really cool shirt you're wearing, where'd you buy it?